# Enunciate with spring mvc rest and other Enunciate Questions

Tags: spring-mvc, wadl, enunciate

Does any knows if Enunciate supports Spring MVC @RequestMapping rest annotations.  If so does anyone have an enunciate.xml and pom.xml file for running the mvn plugin.  The mvn plugin is not merging my web.xml properly..

So how do you rename /api servlet that Enunciate creates ... that is the name of the servlet that I am trying to document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does any knows if Enunciate supports Spring MVC @RequestMapping rest annotations?

Answer: no, just JAX-RS.

> Does anyone have an enunciate.xml and pom.xml file for running the mvn plugin? The mvn plugin is not merging my web.xml properly.

pom.xml:

```
  <project><build><plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>assemble</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

enunciate.xml:

```
<enunciate>
  <webapp mergeWebXML="./path/to/my/web.xml"/>
```

> So how do you rename /api servlet that Enunciate creates?

Enunciate doesn't create a servlet named "/api". Not sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Enunciate does have a spring integration, you can find some more details [here](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/executables.html).

I must add that as for now, I'm struggling with Enunciate in order to make it work with Spring annotations. So far, without success.